# attaching the script debugger to process(5580) iexplorer.exe on machine is failed. a debugger is already attached while running vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am new to visual studio 2010. I hav IE10 and visual studio 2010 and windows 7 32 bit OS.

while running the website I am getting error as "attaching the script debugger to process(5580) iexplorer.exe on machine is failed. a debugger is already attached"

I tried by running this in command prompt run as administrator

regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"

but its not working for me.

how to solve this issue.

Please help me

I am new to visual studio 2010

thank you in advance

shubha

Answer (score 0):

You may have some processes attached to the application pool worker process.
For instance, verify if you have installed and activated "Debug Diagnostic Tool" and uninstall it or just deactivate the rule.